# Rails 4 collection_select is MVC violated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, collection-select

I have a small question about `collection_select` in Rails 4.
When we call in the collection_select all the elements of a table
example:

```
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name %>
```

Is MVC violated?
In other words: if I have a collection_select in the view of products
and it calls `Category.all` in this view, for me we are violated the MVC pattern. Cause `Category.all` is something that should be in a Model.

Tell me if I'm in right.

Comment: Depends on your definition of MVC, and how much you care about view isolation. Really, having the action instance variables is *more* of a violation, IMO-a view, ideally, would only have access to a view-specific model. There are almost always trade offs.

Comment: Umm , so in which case i can talk about violation?

Comment: If it's important to you, sure-but I'm not really sure it's a big deal. "Pure" MVC frameworks are few and far between, although with the proliferation of Web sockets and similar they're becoming more doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a collection to `collection_select` as a list of options is not a violation of MVC pattern, it's just how `collection_select` is seeded with data.

Comment: Maybe i should use a method to take all the categories..or not?

Comment: @Vito the thing about method is that it would be evaluated only when class is loaded, which means it could be not accurate enough.

Comment: Sorry Andrey, but i still really don t understand why , when i call Category.all in a view , it's not a violation. These kind of things should be done in the Model of Category and recalled in the view through an helper or a simpli method. Thx for helping me :)

Comment: @Vito Not in `Category`, but rather a model that goes to the view.